# Why this login form sometimes fails?

Tags: php, jquery, slim

I have login form that usually works but sometimes it fails. When it fails, it doesnt redirect to good page after entering successful credentials. It redirect to /undefined URL.

I am not able to find the cause but would be great if someone can assist me. I am adding whole code.

html part

```
 <div class="container-login100">
    <div class="wrap-login100 p-6">
            <form id="frmLogin" action="/api/v1/login" method="POST">
            <span class="login100-form-title pb-5">
                Login
            </span>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">

                <div class="panel-body tabs-menu-body p-0 pt-5">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab5">
                            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input input-group" data-bs-validate="Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                                <a  class="input-group-text bg-white text-muted">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-email text-muted" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                                <input class="input100 border-start-0 form-control ms-0" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input input-group" id="Password-toggle">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="input-group-text bg-white text-muted">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye text-muted" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                                <input class="input100 border-start-0 form-control ms-0" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn btn-primary" style="cursor: pointer">
                                        Login
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is API login call ( I am using SLIM framework)

```
$app->post('/login', function() use ($app) {
    // check for required params
    verifyRequiredParams(array('username', 'password'));

    // reading post params
    $username = $app->request()->post('username');
    $password = $app->request()->post('password');
    $response = array();
    $db = new DbHandler();

    $password = md5($password);
    $user = $db->getUserByUsername($username, $password);

    if ($user != NULL) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["firstName"] = $user['firstName'];
        if(empty($response["firstName"])){
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "User doesnt exist";
            //exit() ;
        }
        else{
            $response["firstName"] = $user['firstName'];
            $response["lastName"] = $user['lastName'];
            $response["apikey"] = $user["api_key"];
            $response["userId"] = $user["userId"];
            $response["jobTitle"] = $user["jobTitle"];
            $response["address"] = $user["address"];
        }

    } else {
        // unknown error occurred
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "An error occurred. Please try again";
    }

    echoRespnse(200, $response);
});
```

Here is JS

```
 <script> 
    $(document).on('submit','#frmLogin',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.post($(this).attr('action'),data,function(response,status) {
            odg = JSON.stringify(response);
            odg = JSON.parse(odg);
            err = odg.error;
            if(err === false){
                success('Success!');
                setSession(response);
            }
            else{
                error('Incorrect username or password. Please try again!');
            }

        });
    });

    function setSession(data)
    {
        $.post('storeSessionVariables.php',data,function(response,status){
            window.location.href = '/dashboard/pages/index.php';
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is storeSessionVariables.php file:

```
<?php
@session_start();
$_SESSION['apikey'] = $_POST['apikey'];
$_SESSION['userID'] = $_POST['userId'];
$_SESSION['jobPosition'] = $_POST['jobTitle'];
$_SESSION['fName'] = $_POST['firstName'];
$_SESSION['lName'] = $_POST['lastName'];
$_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
echo 1;
```

As I stated at the beginning, it works but sometimes got stuck and redirect in /undefined
I have no clue why is that happening. Any idea, what can I improve here?

Comment: I don't see any way that it can redirect to `/undefined`, since you have the URL hard-coded as `/dashboard/pages/index.php`

Comment: I just tried it and this is what I got, domain.info/dashboard/undefined I use VPN in Australia but server is located in Holland, Europe. Could this be an issue?

Comment: I don't see any way that this code could be doing that. Maybe there's a bad redirect rule on the server.